# ThreadAbortException stopping code from running

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following exception

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. at
>   System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr socketHandle,
>   Byte* pinnedBuffer, Int32 len, SocketFlags socketFlags)

It is when the code is attempting to send an email.

My biggest issue is that when this happens it stops all the rest of my code from running (this is a asp.net site) even though I am catching the exception in a try catch and handling it.

The code does a `foreach` loop and runs fine until this exception is hit at which point I catch the exception in the loop. The loop then exits and non of the other items in the `foreach` are looped through.

```
if (entry.VatInvoiceRequested) 
{
   try 
   {
        using (var email = new EntryVatReceiptEmail(entry.Id)) 
        {
            if (email.NeedReceipt) 
            {
                email.SendEmail();
                email.SendEntryChargeMail();
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Logger.Log4NetLogger.Error("Error sending VAT invoice", ex);
    }
    log.Debug("Entry Handler - About to return from Process()");
}
```

Now, I would expect the last log line to be called but it is  not called when the exception caught. Just for clarification the logging in the catch is working and recorded to the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ThreadAbortException is rethrown after each catch automatically, you can only do Thread.ResetAbort() in catch block..
But don't do this, if your thread is aborted you need to find exact reason.

Comment: the reason looks like a timeout when sending the email via smtp... it is so random we can't see a pattern to why it is happening as the majority of calls are fine (Although it is likely to be a network issue). The problem is that when the exception occurs is causes big problems as payments are not taken properly and the database is left in a bad state... I am normally able to catch exceptions and the code continues... why is it failing to continue in this case?

Comment: _"why is it failing to continue in this case?"_ Because the thread the code is executed on is aborted ... = not running any more after catch block exit. You need to follow the white rabbit - I mean the stacktrace down the rabbit hole until you get to the root cause. Then fix it.

Comment: Okay, I understand. This is going to be a tough cookie to crack... :-(